# Spring wrongfully tries to cast my sealed class into a Collection. Why?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a problem with Spring, kotlin, and sealed classes, and don't know where it comes from. It would seem Spring tries to cast my `ErrorDto` class into a collection, when it shouldn't have to cast it.

## Context

I have a sealed class `Response` that wraps my responses.

```
sealed interface Response<T>

class ErrorResponse<T>(status: HttpStatus, message: String) : Response<T>,
    ResponseEntity<ErrorDto>(ErrorDto(status.value(), message), status)

class SuccessResponse<T>(responseEntity: ResponseEntity<T>) : Response<T>, ResponseEntity<T>(responseEntity.body, responseEntity.headers, responseEntity.statusCode) {
    constructor(body: T): this(ok(body))
}
class ErrorDto(val status: Int, @SerializedName("error") val message: String? = null)
```

All my requests return types are `Response<AType>`, where `AType` is a typical response type so that:

- we have a `ResponseEntity<AType>` when the request **succeeds**,
- and when the request encounters an **error**, it returns a `ResponseEntity<ErrorDto>`

The wrapper `Response` is here so that I can correctly type the responses to the REST requests.

## Working example

This works correctly with custom types, and here is an example of request that **works** at runtime:

```
@GetMapping("/test1")
fun test1(): Response<MyCustomType> {
    val response: Response<MyCustomType> = if (true) {
        ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "test")
    } else {
        SuccessResponse(MyCustomType())
    }
    return response
}
```

## The problem

And now, here's an example of what **doesn't** work at runtime (it compiles just fine):

```
@GetMapping("/test2")
fun test2(): Response<List<String>> {
    val response: Response<List<String>> = if (true) {
        ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "test")
    } else {
        SuccessResponse(listOf("toto"))
    }
    return response
}
```

The runtime error with this `test2` is:

```
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: class ErrorDto cannot be cast to class java.util.Collection
```

## Why?

It would seem that Spring tries to cast the type to a collection when the wrapped response type is a List (`Response<List<String>>` here), when it shouldn't do that.

**Any idea where this problem comes from and why Spring tries to cast to a Collection when it shouldn't do that?**

**N.B.:** As a workaround, I wrapped my List with MyCustomClass in order to go around the problem, but I would still like to understand the *why*.

Comment: Why it tries to change it because that is what you specified... `Response<List<String>>` is clearly a collection. So it isn't Spring but the fact that **you** specified it as such it tries to change it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Read more carefully the definition of `ErrorResponse`. It should not cast it to `T` because I explicitly stated that it is a `ResponseEntity<ErrorDto>`, not of `<T>`

Comment: You state here `val response: Response<List<String>>` that you are returning a `Response<List<String>>` which is a collection. Your `ErrorResponse` isn't. This wouldn't work in Java either both the return values have to match the generic type you specified.

Comment: @M.Deinum It's still in the definition of the sealed  class subclass: you can see that `ErrorResponse<T>` extends `Response<T>` but calls `ResponseEntity<ErrorDto>` => Notice that `T` is not related to `ErrorDto` in any way.
And you can also see that the working example `test1` is of type `Response<MyCustomType>` and is OK with responding a `ResponseEntity<ErrorDto>`.

Comment: Regardless, spring checks the return type of the method expects a `List` doesn't get it and errors out.

Comment: If what you say is true, then why does the `test1` succeed? And it shouldn't be true, because Spring should check for a return type of Response<List<String>>, which it gets, because ErrorResponse implements Response<List<String>>. Even more, `ErrorResponse` implements Response<litterally anything we want>. So Response<Collection> is included in this "litterally anything" too.

Comment: Because of generics. Ultimatly it ends up being a single `ErrorDto` and not a collection. So unless you tap into the Spring handling and write something that knows how to unwind your specific `Response` it won't work. The main issue here is, I suspect, that fact that you say you return a `Response<T>` but underneath also use a `ResponseEntity` which is ultimatly what Spring will detect and deserialize. And a single element doesn't fit into a collection type (you can detect generics just so far).

Comment: Have a look at Kotlin `Result` class. Rather than having a `Success<T>` and `Error<T>` response implementing the same interface try putting that into the same class. If you need a custom error type, prefer a generic `Response<SuccessType,ErrorType>` class instead. This way you can control both types independently from one another.